# Does the Universal Windows Application infrastructure support any Serial Port communications?

Tags: bluetooth, gps, serial-port, usb, win-universal-app

I have a WPF desktop application that would make a good candidate as a Universal Windows App. The application has a must-have dependence on USB or Bluetooth devices that act as a Serial Port.
In all my reading I've yet to discover whether there is any access to a SerialPort API in a UWA.
I suspect the answer is 'No support'.  If so, does anyone know of a USB or Bluetooth GPS that supports whatever APIs the UWA has for that sort of thing. I have to be able to read things like ground speed, elevation, rate of climb, etc.
If the answer is 'Supported', could you point me to some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For the "Bluetooth devices that act as a Serial Port", I assume you mean the RFCOMM. They are both supported on Windows Runtime since Windows 8.1 and you can also use them in the Universal Windows Application.

namespace: Windows.Devices.Usb and Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm.

About the Bluetooth GPS, I'm not sure if it uses RFCOMM or not (it depends on the devices), and it is also possible to use the GATT.

Code Sample: [Custom USB device access sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Custom-USB-device-access-ba5137cc)

Comment: I'm not sure what the various ways are that Bluetooth devices can act as a Serial Port and I see no mention of RFCOMM in the specs for the device I'm testing with nor of GATT. Nowadays there are so many protocols and acronyms that it is impossible to keep up with them all.  I just want to solve the problem, not learn able to various layers of this or that protocol. That being said, would the specs for a BT device typically mention RFCOMM? I could not find any GPS devices that mentioned it, but I suspect that some of them did use RFCOMM. My device mentions SPP (Serial Port Profile).